# Using GWT-Editors without UiBinder

Tags: java, user-interface, gwt, uibinder

I wanted to improve the code of my gwt-project by using editors to bind the POJOs, which I used to manually parse to the widgets back and forth. However I find the [documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors.html) confusing, mostly because it references [ui binder](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html), another feature I haven't figured out yet.

Does it make sense to use editors without ui binder? My ParentDTO contains a number of childDTOs. The following snippet shows how I am trying to nest some ChildEditors extended by TextArea into my ParentEditor (tried to strip it down to the essentials):

```
public class MyEditorPage {

    // editors
    class ParentDTOEditor implements Editor<ParentDTO> {
        Integer dataBaseId;
        List<ChildDTOEditor> childs;

        public void attach(RootPanel rootPanel) {
            for (ChildDTOEditor widget : childs) {
                rootPanel.add(widget);
            }
        }
    }
    class ChildDTOEditor implements Editor<ChildDTO> extends TextArea {}

    // driver
    interface Driver extends SimpleBeanEditorDriver<ParentDTO, ParentDTOEditor> {}
    Driver driver = GWT.create(Driver.class);

    // load set widgets to the root panel
    public void loadPage(RootPanel rootPanel) {

        // get pojos from server
        myService.getSuff(...
            ...
            public void onSuccess(ParentDTO result) {
                ParentDTOEditor editor = new ParentDTOEditor();
                driver.initialize(editor);
                driver.edit(result);
                editor.attach(rootPanel);                   
            }
    }

    // save
    public void save() {
        ParentDTO dto = driver.flush();
        ... // call myService.saveStuff(dto,...
    }
}
```

Do I even need separate editors or just a parent editor of type ListEditor directly holds the child dtos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it make sense to use editors without ui binder?

Yes, the features are independent and each can be used without the other.

> Do I even need separate editors or just a parent editor of type `ListEditor` directly holds the child dtos?

You could create a `ListEditor` implementation direcly, but GWT can do that for you if you tell it how to create and destroy an `Editor<ChildDTO>` by extending `EditorSource<ChildDTOEditor>` and using `ListEditor.of(new YourChildDTOEditorSourceImpl())`

There's a decent example [here](https://sites.google.com/site/mygwtexamples/home/ui/listeditor) but I'll call out a minimum implementation here.

```
public class FooEditor extends Composite implements Editor<Foo> {

    // Implement one of uibinder+fields, fields, methods, or LeafValueEditor.set/getValue()

    public FooEditor() {
        initWidget(/* root widget or call to uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this) */)
    }

}

public class FooListEditor extends Composite implements IsEditor<ListEditor<Foo, FooEditor>> {

    private class FooEditorSource extends EditorSource<FooEditor> {
        @Override
        public FooEditor create(int index) {
            FooEditor subEditor = new FooEditor();

            // any additional per-item config can go here, e.g wiring up delete handler

            listPanel.insert(subEditor, index);

            return subEditor;
        }

        @Override
        public void dispose(FooEditor subEditor) {
            subEditor.removeFromParent();
        }

        @Override
        public void setIndex(FooEditor subEditor, int index) {
            listPanel.insert(subEditor, index);
        }
    }

    // FlowPanel or anything else you want to use to hold the sub-editors.
    // Instantiated explicitly or through uibinder.
    FlowPanel listPanel = new FlowPanel(); 


    // Let GWT handle the ListEdiotr implementation
    ListEditor<Foo, FooEditor> editor = ListEditor.of(new FooEditorSource());

    public FooListEditor() {
        initWidget(listPanel /* or uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this) */);
    }

    @Override
    public ListEditor<Foo, FooEditor> asEditor() {
        return editor;
    }

}
```

Now you can create an editor driver and use it as you would a normal editor, but pass it a list instead.

```
interface Driver extends SimpleBeanEditorDriver<List<Foo>, ListEditor<Foo, FooEditor>> {}
Driver driver = GWT.create(Driver.class);
FooListEditor fooListEditor = new FooListEditor();

/* snip */

driver.initialize(FooListEditor);
driver.edit(someListOfFoo);
```